# Getting bad attitudes from some colleagues at a startup because I insist on using formatter and proper use of TypeScript

Tags: colleagues, startup

So I have been working at a startup for over 6 months now. Two colleagues already have expressed some aversions to using TypeScript or formatters such as prettier when writing code, but if you are going to ask me to do a PR, I am going to comment when I see use of `var` as opposed to `const` and `let`, basically ES6 and beyond as opposed to just whatever floats the boat of the latest hire which is typically using CommonJS module system for new projects because they have not learned the ES2015 Module system and if a project is already a ES2015 project they still use CommonJS module patterns in it or run `node index.js` and say see, no complaints from TypeScript. Right, thats because TS does not exist in when running `node`.

The two founders, seem okay with just getting product out the door as soon as possible rather than following European Computer Machine Association standards and proper use of TypeScript.

Not sure what to do, but I am sure the nay sayers are positioning this to be an issue of me just wasting time with industry standards as opposed to getting product out the door as soon as possible.

To be clear, I am not sure how others interpret standards, but these standards are to catch bugs or to assist in doing so, it's the whole modus operandi of TypeScript and it's the reason we use `const` and `1et` instead of `var`. With `var` you can accidentally mutate that state inside that variable and never notice until it's too let, with `const` you will not be allowed to screw that up.

What to do?

Comment: I prefer a Compile-time error any day over a runtime-error.

Comment: Errors like "let" instead of "late" should always be found - proofreading and error checking is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What to do?

You can see this as a technical decision. Or as a "effort vs cost" decision. And that would not be wrong. But you could also see it for what it is: your company hired people that aren't up to the job. At least not to the standard you expect.

Let me make a comparison for the non-programmers who read this. When you get an office mail, sometimes you get mails that are gramatically incorrect and full of spelling mistakes. And the writer will at some point say "sorry, I didn't have much time and didn't pay attention". And they think that this is a good reason. What I see is not someone who did not have enough time. What I see is a person so inept in this skill (in the case of the email riddled with mistakes the skill of communicating in their native language's written form) that doing it correctly costs them actual, conscious effort. They just told you, that if they do not concentrate their full brain power on the task of writing in their native language, something that should come effortless if you finished school, they cannot do it. If writing simple *but correct* English takes *longer* than writing bad English, then English is not a skill you have mastered. You are still an apprentice. I mean we are not talking Shakespear here, we are talking about an everyday conversation through email. The problem is not time, the problem is skill. And since skill is lacking, they need more time. Needing more time is the visible effect of the problem, not the actual problem. The actual problem is missing skill.

And to end this analogy, and come back to programming in the office, I personally want to work with people who write code clean and precise and maintainable as default. If this is "extra work" that costs "extra time", then they obviously lack skills that I *expect* from my colleagues.

If someone told me to save time by not capitalizing certain words in English, I would probably need *extra time* to make sure my muscle memory *doesn't* capitalize them. Because I don't think about it consciously.

So if someone tells me they save time by not following the little rules of programming, what they actually tell me is they are not skilled enough to follow those simple rules in their sleep.

So what can you do?

Well, your colleagues -by their own admission- lack basic skills and they won't learn them overnight, *if ever*. You can accept that because they pay you enough to work with less skilled personal, or you can find a company that doesn't hire clowns. But it's highly unlikely that they will change, just because you say so. Their standards might be lower than yours or maybe they simply don't know enough to even have standards. But that's how they operate.

Comment: you get it. Thank you, I am not insane after all. I have given myself two weeks to figure out where I want to go next in my career and if this start up will be a part of that future...exciting times.

Answer (score 10):

The founders may have a clearer understanding of the phrase, "Don't let perfection get in the way of good enough." Unless there are specific industry standards that your software must be certified to meet, the "good enough" principle is going win over perfection every day.

I love standards and processes but I also understand they come with an initial cost and not everyone is always a fan. You might want to try starting with a style guide. If you can pull it off, that will get people moving in an agree-upon direction.

Also, remember that the goal of any software department isn't to generate beautiful code, it's to deliver value to the broader organization. I'm pretty sure that's what your founders care about.

Comment: totally get you, but as someone who was interviewing for jobs not that long ago, in an interview "good enough" will not fly. They will want to see proper use of type annotations and so on and so forth and I guess what I want to avoid at all costs is learning bad habits.

Comment: I also edited my OP, because based on your answer I am getting the feeling that once again, the point of these standards is being missed, its not for style or to look beautiful is to help us catch bugs.

Comment: @Daniel What "will fly", isn't up to you. Unless you're the CEO who gets to set the standards. If you don't like organisational standards, you should consider leaving. Make sure you include how important "let" is to you during your interview.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, I am usually asked whether I use ES6 standards during interviews in the past, its why I am shocked by this behavior, but then again I have typically avoided startups like the plague, now I know why, "grow faster" is more important than quality code. In regards to it not being up to me, that is not what I am complaining about. Lets see if I can put it in a way you can understand, you got your welders certification and now are at a team that says oh it does not have to be welded correctly, just enough to get it out the door...ouch. Do you want to be responsible for that?

Comment: @Daniel I'm not a pipefitter, so that analogy is lost on me. If the interview was not representative of the work, it's not the best. But trying to change the organisational culture to match your interview experience is really not going to work without buy-in from above.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, fair enough. the CTOs deciding to not buy-in to when I was telling him the backend engineer was going to cost him time and money, then that engineer cost him time and money and got fired as a result. Its deja vu, I am okay with going into a corner shutting up and doing my work and watching it all cost them time and money again. Someone here said money is limited at a startup, I am talking about implementation to help catch bugs before they go out, the idea is to save time and money as opposed to letting that tech debt build that will eventually cost time and money.

Comment: @Daniel Nothing has changed in the tech world. There continues to be a lot of different companies with a lot of different changes. The only universal rule is there are no universal rules.

Comment: *"Don't let perfection get in the way of good enough."* - I'm writing that one down ;) ... oh I am a bit torn with this situation you describe @Daniel but I do think that the Style Guide will give you something more *tangible* and structured for the CTO and others to have as a starting point for you to propose. If your concern is that people are confusing your posture as "seeking perfection" but you actually want to catch bugs faster, then do include on that Style Guide (or in demos) ways or examples of how a guide can/has helped catch bugs faster.

Comment: @DarkCygnus, now there is an idea I can get behind. Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel, you indicate in one of your responses that the purpose of the standards is to catch bugs. I have 33 years of experience writing software for all kinds of complex systems and on only one project for 3 years did we have "standards". I ran a CCM Level 3 project that produced 8 releases of zero-defect software where every release was delivered ahead of schedule and under budget. On every other project I've ever worked on I was simply expected to deliver the best possible software as soon as possible. Management isn't paying you for bugs. You have to do what it takes to deliver quality.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at it from the other side. Those chaps are not being paid to change how they work and you have no authority over them. So you can expect resistance unless you can show them how it will benefit them in the short term.

Which as far as I can see won't happen. They already have bosses and you aren't one of them.

Which leaves your bosses to decide if it's worth the effort and tension to take your side. This is risky because if 2 performing workers have an issue with a third, it's a fairly simple equation that the third is the problem. So be prepared for any pushing to potentially go against you.

There is two ways to make a change. One is through the hierarchy which hasn't worked. The other is sideways by showing your colleagues how it will benefit them personally and tangibly in the short term. Not how it will benefit the product or long term benefits for the company. It's not their product or company. It's a startup that quite possibly won't be around in a year or two.

Comment: @Killisi, I am never clear how people misinterpret my posts. Correct, I am not their boss and they are not mine, but I am being told NOT to follow standards by these same guys, that I have it wrong.

Comment: Sure you are, that's a defence mechanism. Justification/rationalisation for just continuing as they are. Recognise it for what it is, not it's face value.

Comment: yes I do know its a defense mechanism on their part, my concern is when it becomes disrespectful, the talking down to, because I suggested a fix that takes one second and can avoid a world of problems afterwards.

Comment: Thats how it works unfortunately. The more defensive, the nastier it can get. Normal social dynamics

Comment: your answer being the most reasonable thus far, I just wanted to say, I am not trying to change how anyone works, a pull request is where someone tells me to check their code to ensure its of good quality, in that context, I tell them, you need to change this for it to be of an improved quality and to avoid the loud errors that the application is screaming at you, to which they say, I don't agree and proceed to add their new feature, bugs and all and yes the owners seem to be okay with that. I am amazed frankly.

Comment: Why amazed? There is two ways to make a change. One is through the hierarchy which hasn't worked. The other is sideways by showing your colleagues how it will benefit them personally and tangibly in the short term. Not how it will benefit the product or long term benefits for the company. It's not their product or company. It's a startup that quite possibly won't be around in a year or two.

Comment: @Kilsi, Amazed because I have never worked at a company that bucked ECMAScript specifications. I expected for those who call themselves JS developers to follow ECMAScript specifications. At this point, the outcome I want to achieve is to be left alone and not told that I am wrong for wanting to follow the specifications of the programming language I am trained in.

Comment: I've never heard of those specs, so they must be applicable in only some locales? I see var being used all the time in Stack Overflow, are they all wrong? (I'm not a developer)

Comment: check the age of the posts on SO when you see `var`, they are pre-2015 syntax. As far as the specs, you can learn more about them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript, the folks at the European Computer Machine Association decided in 2015 they would start to come out with new specifications ever since. I think they are trying to make JS more OOP. The irony here is Brendan Eich was being rushed to get to market fast and so he did not get to make JavaScript a true OOP language, the folks at ECMA, I believe are trying to finish making JS more OOP with classes and such.

Comment: and the main guy giving me pushback at work, is actually mad that the folks at ECMA are trying to make JS more OOP and that there is an effort to make it more strongly typed via TypeScript. Its like buddy go get a career in another language then, because I am a JS developer because I love where things are going with it. But instead I feel like everyone is telling me I should do things the way this guy wants them done...no I am doing things according to specs, I love where its going, let him go invent another language and rewire it how he wants and it will cost this company in the end

Comment: @Daniel I'm not a developer, thats all meaningless to me, no offence. But I have seen var used plenty in recent years on Stack Overflow. You seem to have taken some specifications as gospel. Unfortunately that doesn't obligate anyone else to as well.

Comment: @Kilisi Just for your info, the specifications don't mandate or even recommend you avoid "var". When Daniel says they are not following "ECMAScript specifications" he is incorrect. They are going against some style guides, of course, but not the spec itself.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Thanks, people interpret things differently sometimes. If they're trained a certain way it tends to stick, nothing particularly wrong with that until it causes conflict

Answer (score 1):

Consider a return-on-investment perspective. You’re at a startup. Money is limited. Apply the formula: Average hourly cost of employee X time discussed X number of people.

Is a conversation, block, rejection, or code update of a feature due to `var` vs `let` going to affect the bottom line? Is this worth potentially thousands of dollars in the near term? Have you achieved minimum viable product and gone to market? Is there substantial net gain by enforcing it?

Standards are great but functionally (and historically) startups need to focus on revenue and that means MVP and new features as quick as possible—not beautiful and semantically correct code.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135699/discussion-on-answer-by-coll-getting-bad-attitudes-from-some-colleagues-at-a-sta).